# Conditionally append dataframes to specific levels of a nested list

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply, mapply

I have a nested list (`mylist`), and I would like to `cbind` a dataframe (`colors`) automatically to a lower level list (`iris`) only if the name of the list contains a specific string (`iris`), but I'm running into a few errors.

Example:

```
mylist <- list(favorites=list("iris"=iris[1:5,], "mtcars"=mtcars[1:5,], "ToothGrowth"=ToothGrowth[1:5,]), misc = list("air"=airquality))
colors <- data.frame(dark = "black", light = "white", mid = "violet")
```

I'd like to append `colors` only to the nested list, `iris`, essentially: `cbind(mylist$favorites$iris, colors)`.  My real dataset is much larger, and manually using `cbind` on each nested list is not possible.

Such that:

```
> cbind.fill(mylist$favoritres$iris, colors)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  dark light    mid
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa black white violet
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa black white violet
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa black white violet
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa black white violet
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa black white violet
```

My current attempt at a solution:

```
mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {
    if(grepl("iris", x$favorites)==TRUE){
        x$favorites <- lapply(x$favorites, function(y) cbind(y, colors))
        }; x
    })
```

Which throws the error:

> Error in if (grepl("iris", x$favorites) == TRUE) { : 
>     argument is of length zero

Comment: `cbind.fill`, I'd like the entries in each column of `colors` to be propagated with all rows of `iris`. updated example

Answer (score 2):

We could create a logical condition to append

```
library(rowr)
mylist2 <- lapply(mylist, function(x)  {
       i1 <- names(x) == "iris"
        x[i1] <- lapply(x[i1], function(y) cbind.fill(y, colors))
        x
   })
```

Comment: This works, but is there a solution that avoids creating a new list?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive solution that will find "iris" regardless of how deeply it is nested in your list:

```
library(rowr)

bind_search <- function(the_list, the_df, matching_name) {

  for (n in names(the_list)) {

    if (n == matching_name && is.data.frame(the_list[[n]])) {
      the_list[[n]] <- cbind.fill(the_list[[n]], the_df)
      return(the_list)
    }

    the_list[[n]] <- bind_search(the_list[[n]], the_df, matching_name)
    return(the_list)
  }
}

mylist2 <- bind_search(mylist, colors, 'iris')
```